# iOS swift : get location from event.structuredLocation of calendar entry

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, calendar

I evaluate calendar data and would have liked to continue using the data in CLLoation format, but with:

```
    po structuredLocation! .geoLocation! .value (forKey: "course") or similar
```

do I not get the latitude / longitude?
How does it work?

```
    func getLocationOfEvent(event: EKEvent, eventLocation: inout CLLocation?) 
    -> String {
      var structuredLocation: EKStructuredLocation?
    
      if event.location != nil {
        structuredLocation = event.structuredLocation
        eventLocation = event.structuredLocation!.geoLocation
      }
    
      if event.location == nil {
        return "<<<Location>>>"
    } else {
        return event.location!    /// String
    }
}
```

and from debugger:
(lldb) po structuredLocation!.geoLocation!
<+50.123456,+8.123456> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 25.09.20, 18:57:08 Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit

How does it work? Or Who knows how to do that?
Grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

You will find latitude, longitude, altitude and other info from EKEventStructuredLocation.

```
if event.location != nil {
    structuredLocation = event.structuredLocation
    print(event.structuredLocation?.geoLocation?.coordinate.latitude)
    print(event.structuredLocation?.geoLocation?.coordinate.longitude)
    print(event.structuredLocation?.geoLocation?.altitude)
        
  }
```

Add this properties to your CLLocation Object and you are good to go...